# How to write nodeJS query to fetch last 24 hours records of postgreSQL database using datetime INTERVAL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgresql-11

I am fetching last 24 hours records from PostgreSQL DB using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '24 hours'` in my `.js` file. But I am not able to write it properly due to single inverted commas in query.

I am fetching records from PostgreSQL database and showing them in terms of bar chart using angular 6.

Here is the query I am trying to run from `.js` file to fetch last 24 hours records:

```
query = {

    name: 'fetch-chart-data24',

    text: ' SELECT availablecar, recentTime, adrs FROM stations_logs WHERE adrs = $1 AND recentTiontime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '24 hours' ORDER BY recentTime desc',

    values: [req.body.adrs,req.body.param]
}
```

Final result from query should be most recent 24 hours records for database.
Currently I am getting error as

> Unexpected number

Answer (score 0):

You can `escape` single quotes with back slahes (`\`) like this:

```
{
  ...
  text: ' SELECT availablecar, recentTime, adrs FROM stations_logs WHERE adrs = $1 AND recentTiontime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL \'24 hours\' ORDER BY recentTime desc',
  ...
}
```

---

For further reading:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-strings-in-javascript#conclusion

Answer (score 0):

```
query = {
    name: 'fetch-chart-data24',
    text: `SELECT availablecar, recentTime, adrs FROM stations_logs WHERE adrs = $1 AND recentTiontime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '24 hours' ORDER BY recentTime desc`,
    values: [req.body.adrs,req.body.param]
}
```

You can make use of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Its for embedding expressions, but can satisfy your use case too.